# Cannot PUT error in Node Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, put

My `get` and `post` APIs are working, but for some reason my `app.put` isn't.

[image]

When I hit `localhost:3001/contacts/1` as a `PUT` in [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/), I don't even see my simple console.log:

[image]

```
app.put('/api/contacts:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.params.id', req.params.id);
    res.json(contact);
});
```

#### app.put

```
app.put('/api/contacts:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.params.id', req.params.id);
    res.json(contact);
});
```

#### Full server.js code

```
// Requires ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // req.body
const cors = require('cors');
const R = require('ramda');

// Variables ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3001;
let contacts = require('./data');

// Logic ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/contacts', (req, res) => {
    if (!contacts || R.isEmpty(contacts)) returnError(res, 'No Contacts found');
    res.json(contacts);
});

app.get('/api/contacts/:id', (req, res) => {
    const contact = contacts.filter(contact => contact.id == req.params.id);
    if (R.isEmpty(contact)) returnError(res, 'No Contact found');
    res.json(R.head(contact));
});

app.post('/api/contacts', (req, res) => {
    const contact = {
        id: contacts.length + 1,
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        website: req.body.website
    }

    contacts.push(contact);

    res.json(contact);
});

app.put('/api/contacts:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.params.id', req.params.id);
    // const contact = contacts.filter(contact => {
    //  return contact.id == req.params.id
    // })[0];

    // console.log('1 contact', contact);
    // const index = contacts.indexOf(contact);
    // const keys = Object.keys(req.body);
    // keys.forEach(key => {
    //  contact[key] = req.body[key];
    // });
    // console.log('2 contact', contact);
    // contacts[index] = contact;
    // console.log('contacts', contacts);
    // res.json(contacts[index]);
    res.json(contact);
});

const returnError = (res, msg) => res.status(404).json({ message: msg });

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`server is running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `'/api/contacts:id'` should be `'/api/contacts/:id'`. If this is so, the question should be closed/deleted as it doesn't introduce any value to future readers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like a typo in this line:

```
app.put('/api/contacts:id', (req, res) => {
```

Add a '/' to read:

```
app.put('/api/contacts/:id', (req, res) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL looks like this:

```
app.put('/api/contacts:id', (req, res) => {,
```

But it should be like this:

```
app.put('/api/contacts/:id', (req, res) => {
```